# Easy way to see changes between core sets?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there an easy way to see which cards were added and removed between core sets?

For example, by looking up the card [Giant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189879) I can see that it was in both M10 and M11, but was not included in M12.  Now on a single-card basis, it's not too hard, but I've got a lot of M11 that I want to go through and see which cards are still legal in standard, and searching Gatherer by card will get pretty tiring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

wiki.mtgsalvation.com is your friend.

http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Magic_2012/Changes, for instance, has complete lists of all the cards that were added to M12 and removed from M11.  You can find the same information for all previous core sets too.

In addition, there are useful sections on changes in rarity from previous printings, and also a running tally of cards that had (up to that date) been included in every Core Set.  Go go Giant Spider!

Comment: I mourn for Giant Growth. :(

Comment: Yes; without Giant Growth it doesn't *feel* like core Magic, somehow.  Ah well.  It'll be back.

Comment: I like Giant Spider better: green pump is all well and good, but the spider is the perfect creature design: not flashy, not powerful, but the crucial glue that holds the whole flyers-versus-non-flyers combat dynamic together.  I don't think it matters whether a set has a 1cc or 2cc Giant Growth analogue; but the 4-drop that blocks all common flyers and survives is irreplaceable IMO!

Comment: well, Mutagenic Growth could be considered a better replacement, because as long as you have more than 2 life you can play it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you could use the compact listing of Gatherer to [show all the cards in M11](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&output=compact&set=%20%5B%22Magic%202011%22%5D) or show [all the cards in M10](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&output=compact&set=%20%5B%22Magic%202010%22%5D), and then quickly visually scan which ones do not include the M12 symbol. It's easy to see because the symbols are in release order, newest first.

Alas, search limitations don't allow you to "filter" cards that are NOT in Standard or M12.

Using this method I was able to find this piece of trivia: there is only one card printed in M10 or M11, but not in M12, that is still Standard tournament legal: [Shatter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194147). It was printed in Scars of Mirrodin.

Comment: Although that could work, it's still not as easy as a list already provided, such as the one @thesunneverset posted